# To send SMS through my Blackberry application to various mobile devices

Tags: blackberry

Can anyone please help me out.

I have developed an application to send SMS to various mobile devices (referring to Blackberry JDE Samples).  Now, the problem is that when i click on the "Send Message" menu item, amount for sending the SMS is deducted from my account but the message is not delievering to some of the mobile devices like Nokia 7210, Nokia 3310 etc. that are lower versions, but when i am sending the same SMS to other HTC mobiles, then it is working fine.

So, what can be the problem that SMS are not sent to some of the mobile devices, but on HTC mobiles, messages are delievered correctly.

I am using Blackberry 8310 for testing my app.
Operating System- v4.5.0.52

Looking forward to hear from u soon.

Comment: Sounds very strange, maybe a problem with your operator?

Comment: post the code, will check whats wrong